# How to add test ids to Stream Chat React Native

Tags: react-native, appium-android, gui-testing, wdio

I'm working on UI tests using wdio and Appium. The app I'm testing includes Stream Chat's MessageInput component ([link to components docs](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/reactnative/ui-components/message-input/)). Inside this component, there's a send button, and I want to make that button clickable (add an accessibility or test id to this button) for my wdio tests. Currently, my appium inspector and wdio cannot find the accessibility id for the send button. Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Here's the code for my component:

```
<MessageInput
  compressImageQuality={0.7}
  additionalTextInputProps={{
    placeholderTextColor: 'grey',
    placeholder:
      channel && channel.data.name
        ? 'Send Message...'
        : 'Message',
  }}
  Input={(props) =>
    // <View marginBottom={hp(2)}>
    <InputBox props={props} open={open} settoTrue={() => setOpen(true)} setOpen={() => { setOpen(false) }} />
    // </View>
  }
/>
```